How to set default ruler measurements for new imports in Inkscape
I need to measure several PDFs, but in cm, not px.  Whenever I import a PDF and pick the measurement tool, I have to change its units.  Is there a way to set the default for all documents, not just the current one?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  If you set the Measure Tool units option to cm, the application should remember the setting, even if you quit Inkscape, and open another PDF.  It seems to work that way in Inkscape 1.3.2. What version of Inkscape are you using?

@BillyKerr Ouch, thank you, you're right.  My distro's version is way out of date at Inkscape 0.92.5 (2060ec1f9f, 2020-04-08)!

Yep, that fixed it.  And cheesy as it may sound: wow, Inkscape has really improved in the last 4 years!  I love how the measure tool has an info popup about the current group on hover, for example ✔

there's a lot of new things in Inkscape to discover. A shapebuilder tool, multiple page support, and also live path effects.

Upgrade to 1.3.2.  Somewhere between 0.92.5 and now, this was fixed.
